# Error creating 3 different graphics in the same png file using gnuplot and java.lang.Runtime and without any Library

Tags: java, gnuplot

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // Set up the gnuplot command and arguments
        String[] cmd = {"gnuplot", "-e", 
                "set terminal png; set output 'plotS.png'; plot 'graficoS.txt' using 1:2 with lines"};
        String[] cmd2 = {"gnuplot", "-e", 
                "set terminal png; set output 'plotS.png'; replot 'graficoI.txt' using 1:3 with lines"};
        String[] cmd3 = {"gnuplot", "-e", 
                "set terminal png; set output 'plotS.png'; replot 'graficoR.txt' using 1:4 with lines"};

        // Start the processes
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        process.waitFor();
        Process process2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd2);
        process2.waitFor();
        Process process3 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd3);
        process3.waitFor();

        // Read the output from the processes
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        reader.close();
}
```

Not showing nothing on the png file , even the gnuplot graphic. In different png files its working , but in the same it isn't.

Comment: What is your error and what is the question? I can't find a question mark in your question. Why are you starting 3 processes/commands instead of one? Maybe you want to do something like that: `String[] cmd = {"gnuplot", "-e", "set terminal png; set output 'plotS.png'; plot 'graficoS.txt' u 1:2 w l, 'graficoI.txt' u 1:3 w l, 'graficoR.txt' u 1:4 w l"};`

Comment: @theozh is right. I'd be happy to help but All you did was write "`java.lang.Runtime`" and paste your code. What was the stacktrace exactly? Where was the error thrown? What are you doing? Ect... More info is needed.